# ERROR : Compiled formula is too big to execute 6050 .Max size is 5000 chars

Tags: formula

I have a requirement   :

1)If  Commercial_Vs_Government__c ,"Government" AND Region__c = 'North America' should be only "Public Sector".

2)Country is : CA then value will be CA.

3)when Commercial_Vs_Government__c is not equals to Government
If state is :ME:VT:NH ...............value will be UE

4)when Commercial_Vs_Government__cis not equals to Government
 If state is :AK:WA:OR ......... Value will be UW

5)if Region  is LA then value is LA.

Here Commercial_Vs_Government__c is a picklist ,Region is a formula field .
I get an Error as

```
ERROR : Complied formula is too big to execute 6050 .Max size is 5000 chars
```

I tried the formulae as :

```
 IF(ISPICKVAL( Commercial_Vs_Government__c ,"Government"),"Public Sector",

IF(CONTAINS("CA",BillingCountry),"CA",

IF(AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Commercial_Vs_Government__c,"Government")),
OR(
BillingState= "ME",
BillingState= "VT",
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


)), "UE",

IF(AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Commercial_Vs_Government__c,"Government")),
OR(
BillingState= "AK",
BillingState= "WA",
BillingState= "OR",
.
.
.
.
.
.
.'



)), "UW",


IF(AND(CONTAINS("PE:VE:..................................................................................................................................................................,BillingCountry),(Region__c="LA")),"LA",

"Undefined")))))
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of long IF chains you can use CONTAINS method -- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004749&language=en_US. If formula is still big -- divide that by two fields, and it would not hit the limitations

Answer (score 3):

Case statement is more appropriate here. It prevents repeating the fieldname over and over again. As an example:

```
CASE(BillingState,

"ME", "UE",
"VT", "UE",
"AK", "UW",
"WA", "UW",

"None")
```

Check [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm) in Salesforce Help for more information.